# get checkbox value by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

there is dynamic checkbox like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" name="user_mail_check[]" class="ami">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2" name="user_mail_check[]" class="ami">
<input type="checkbox"  value="3" name="user_mail_check[]" class="ami">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" name="user_mail_check[]" class="ami">
<input type="checkbox"  value="5" name="user_mail_check[]" class="ami">
```

How can I get value of each checked checkbox.

I used

```
$('.ami').is(":checked").value();
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `value()` function use `val()` You can use each to iterate through the elements with class `ami`,

```
$('.ami:checked').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: you're selecting all checkboxes, not only the the checked ones

Comment: close alert box like : `alert($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.ami').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give all the checked values in an array.

```
var values = $('.ami').map(function(i,el){
    if($(el).is(':checked')){
        return $(el).val()
    }
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$('.ami').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){ 
    $(this).val(); // get checked value
  }
});
```